# Does MessageBox work out of browser in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

If I use MessageBox will it continue to work if I make my application an out of browser app?  It looks like a javascript alert...

Comment: This should be fairly easy to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually a "javascript alert" (the host is supplying the alert not javascript) looks like an ordinary OS message dialog.  It just so happens that the browser `alert` method and the Silverlight `MessageBox` ultimately invoke this same operating system feature.

So the answer to your question: Yes it does.